# poisson rate and uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question : Customers arrive at a bank at a Poisson rate $\lambda$. Suppose that we already know that exactly two customers arrive during the first hour.

What is the expected arrival time of the first customer ?

I think that the two customers are uniformly dist on $(0,1)$ so the ans should be 20 mins?
Since there is a conditional, I think the distribution changes and is not Poisson anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

The joint conditional distribution for the arrival times in the interval, under the condition that there are exactly two, is that for the order statistics for two identical and independent uniformly distributed samples over the interval.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is an order statistics ?

Comment: Take several independent and identically distributed random samples then arrange them in order of magnitude.  Those are the order statistics of the samples.  Usually labeled $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, \ldots X_{(n)}$ for the lowest to $n^{\sf th}$ highest order statistic.

Comment: and may I also ask, how is it related to the question above ? Im very sorry, but kind of lost